# Javascript shorthand for calling a callback function if it is not null?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If we have:

```
(cb)=>{ if (cb!=null) cb()}
```

Is there are shorter way to check if cb is not null and call it?  This will be running on Node.

Comment: For the record, good code is not shorter, it's more readable

Comment: Agreed, there's nothing wrong with that as it is.

Comment: This code's syntax is wrong

Comment: Just `if (cb) cb()` should do, but `if (typeof cb=="function") cb()` would be better. Arguably, don't ever use optional callback parameters anyway…

Comment: `cb?.()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check `cb` directly.

In the case where `cb` is a function, you get a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value as first check and then it calls the function.

If `cb` is `null`, then the first part is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) and the second does not get executed.

```
cb => cb && cb()
```

Comment: That's what I tought too XD  but I was trying to understand the missing parenthesis in the function

Comment: @Phiter look at the ES6 arrow-function feature

Comment: Notice that this does return something else than the original function.

Comment: `cb => cb && cb() && undefined` would fix that, but if I saw that code, I'd walk away.

Comment: @mr.void I'm aware of arrow functions, I mean that the `if` is missing the closing parenthesis, the code syntax is wrong.

Comment: YES - That's what I was looking for - Thanks!!

Answer (score 11):

Now in 2021 : [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```
cb?.()
```

If cb is `null` - cb is **not** invoked.

if cb is a func, cb **is** invoked.

Note: if cb is a not function or a non null/undefined value, (eg 23 or false) then this will throw a TypeError.